# How use two jssor with out jquery sliders on one page

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

hi iam use two jssor slider in one page .iam use Different slider uses different name but dont show slider in page.iam dont whats problem.
this my code iam change two jssor silder name  but dont work.please help.tahnks

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
    <script>
        jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $AutoPlaySteps: 4,
              $SlideDuration: 160,
              $SlideWidth: 200,
              $SlideSpacing: 3,
              $Cols: 4,
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $Steps: 4
              },
              $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
                $SpacingX: 1,
                $SpacingY: 1
              }
            };

            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 809);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };
    </script>

    <!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
    <script>
        jssor_2_slider_init = function() {

            var jssor_2_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $AutoPlaySteps: 4,
              $SlideDuration: 160,
              $SlideWidth: 200,
              $SlideSpacing: 3,
              $Cols: 4,
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $Steps: 4
              },
              $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
                $SpacingX: 1,
                $SpacingY: 1
              }
            };

            var jssor_2_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_2", jssor_2_options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 809);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };
    </script>


  <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 809px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 809px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">

        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
        <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb03" style="bottom:10px;right:10px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div data-u="prototype" style="width:21px;height:21px;">
                <div data-u="numbertemplate"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

  <div id="jssor_2" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 809px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 809px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">

        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
        <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb03" style="bottom:10px;right:10px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div data-u="prototype" style="width:21px;height:21px;">
                <div data-u="numbertemplate"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
 <script>
        jssor_1_slider_init();
       jssor_2_slider_init();
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/xc86js21/  i have embeded 2 sliders here

Comment: tanks it work for me